# Unable to load modules with my current python project structure

Tags: python

I have created a Flask application in `portal/webapp.py`. When I try to start the application using `python portal/webapp.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "portal/webapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from db import TenantManager, QueryHandler
  File "****/Project/portal/db.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sql_parser.SQLParserTools import Parser, Builder
ImportError: No module named sql_parser.SQLParserTools
```

Here is my project structure

```
Project/
    portal/
        __init__.py
        db.py
        manage.py
        test/
            __init__.py
            test_db.py
        webapp.py
    sql_parser/
        __init__.py
        error.py
        SQLParserTools.py
        StringParsers.py
        test/
            __init__.py
            test_parser.py
```

Comment: Is `_init__.py` (line -1) with only one underscore a copy/paste error or a genuine error ?

Comment: copy/paste error, thanks!

Comment: What is your 'PYTHONPATH' variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `..../Project/` to your `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Note that since there is no `__init__.py` in Project. You consider that `portal` and  `sql_parser` are two different project. One which is using the other.

Comment: So if I add an `__init__.py` file to Project, would I still need to modify the `PYTHONPATH` var?

Comment: Yes by putting the parent of `Projet`.